# JQuery - appending selects from $('select') to $('input') object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

how i have following piece of code:

```
var $form = $(form);
$fields = $form.find('input[name]');
$selects = $form.find('select');
```

How can i concat $selects to $fields? I want  inputs and selects in one JQuery Object.

Comment: Are you mixing PHP and JavaScript in there?

Answer (score 1):

as you have created the jquery object of form from variable form. variable form should be dom object.

Then you can use comma separated multiple elements:

```
var $objects= $(form).find('input[name],select');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap form in `" ...  "`

```
var $objects= $("form").find('input[name],select');
```